# Where do I download Unity from?

Tags: unity, software-installation

I'm new to Linux and I'm wondering how to install Unity from windows. I've looked online and only found an old Unity install from launchpad but it hasn't looked active since last year.

Comment: It's probably possible to do, but it's more of a parlor trick than something practical right now.  The best (i.e. easiest) solution would probably be to install Virtualbox, then run an Ubuntu virtual machine within it

Comment: Do you want to install Unity in Ubuntu *from Windows*, or do you want to install Unity under the the LXS in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

There is an article on OMG! Ubuntu! at http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/someone-just-installed-unity-windows giving a pointer to a description of the process to have Unity run on the Ubuntu subsystem of Windows 10. Quote: *"the entire run-through is not for the faint hearted"*.